# Should I tune a learner with the whole dataset?

Tags: r, mlr3

Recently I was learning about using mlr3 package, and I got some problems:

(1) I read [The "Cross-Validation - Train/Predict" misunderstanding](https://mlr-org.com/docs/cv-vs-predict/). This sounds to me that: I should focus on the average unbiased estimate performance of the model as the result of nested sampling. To me, tuning is adding CV in the training set (i.e., find the best hyperparameters and the feature importance rank), just like the figure below.
[image: A Data Analysis Plan]
However, many examples in the mlr3gallery (e.g., [tuning a SVM](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2021-03-09-practical-tuning-series-tune-a-support-vector-machine/); [tuning a graph](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2021-03-11-practical-tuning-series-build-an-automated-machine-learning-system/)) seem to tune their learners with the whole dateset, which confused me. Is it appropriate to use all the data for tuning learner?

(2) I wonder if there is any way to combine *Feature Selection* and *Model Tuning* together. I find the function in mlr [feature-filtering-with-tuning](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/nested_resampling.html#example-3-one-task-two-learners-feature-filtering-with-tuning-1), but not in mlr3. I guess a pipeline graph might be help, but I could not find a tutorial.

Thanks a lot! Any helps would be grateful!

Comment: mlr divides the data internally according to the specified resampling when tuning. And yes, a pipeline is the way to do this in mlr3, see mlr3pipelines.

Comment: Use CV to estimate (unbiased) performance. If you want to train the "final" model which you want to use for prediction, tune it on the "full dataset".

Comment: @LengJH It is good practice to only ask a single question per post on Stackoverflow. To combine filtering with tuning (which is a very common practice) mlr3pipelines should be used.